# go-aop-php wont work even with simple setup

Tags: php, aop

I cant seem to make go-aop-php library work for me and I have no idea why.

Basically I have go-aop-php 0.6.0 installed with composer and simple code which I ripped off from the available examples.

Here's the [GIST](https://gist.github.com/andreyvk/e7e9ad97d735fba42037) of my code.

Attached below is the directory structure (if it's of any help):

[image]

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 with PHP 5.5. I am also wondering if I missed any dependencies for go-aop-php to operate properly.

Comment: You haven't said what didn't work? What does it do? What doesn't it do? Where is your **isolated** and **self contained** problem code? What is the expected output? What is the actual output? What errors do you get? Have you debugged your code? Have you checked the logs.

Comment: Well it's AOP, right? So it does not kick in when it's supposed to. Basically, I am expecting TestClass to output a certain message and then before that AOP must kick in and output it's own message.

Answer (score 0):

Go! AOP is not a magic tool and can not change already loaded class to weave an aspect into it. In your case you explicitly load class via direct `require_once __DIR__.'/classes/TestClass.php';` expression. After that class is already loaded and AOP won't be applied.

To fix your issue, you should use a composer for class autoloading (Go! AOP intercepts this automatically).

PS. If you will have any questions or need a support, please open an issue on GitHub instead. StackOverflow isn't a place to discuss such issues. I will be glad to help you with any issues on GitHub

Comment: Did not think it was a bug or issue worth posting in the development issue tracker. I will recreate this issue there if it's more convenient this way,